# Initialize ipython notebook server from .ipynb file

Tags: ipython

Is it possible to open EIN notebook as file, so it automatically takes care of starting `ipython notebook` server?

Answer (score 1):

There is [`ein:jupyter-server-start`](http://millejoh.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/#ein:jupyter-server-start), which should do as you want. It should drop you directly onto the notebook list, from which the notebooks are easily accessible.

> If you are particularly lucky ein will also determine the access url and token authentication for the running server and automatically log you in.

Comment: It is not the same thing, `ein:jupyter-server-start` open the directory containing the ipynb files, then you have to open the ipynb file manually.